# remove element from python list based on match from another list

Tags: python, list

I have list of s3 objects like this:

```
list1 = ['uid=123/2020/06/01/625e2ghvh.parquet','uid=876/2020/04/01/hgdshct7.parquet','uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']

list2 = ['123','876']

result_list = ['uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']
```

With out using any loop is there any efficient way to achieve this considering large no of elements in list1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a `set` from `list2` for a faster lookup and use a list comprehension to check for membership using the substring of interest:

```
list1 = ['uid=123/2020/06/01/625e2ghvh.parquet','uid=876/2020/04/01/hgdshct7.parquet',
         'uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']
list2 = ['123','876']
set2 = set(list2)

[i for i in list1 if i.lstrip('uid=').split('/',1)[0] not in set2]
# ['uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']
```

---

The substring is obtained through:

```
s = 'uid=123/2020/06/01/625e2ghvh.parquet'
s.lstrip('uid=').split('/',1)[0]
# '123'
```

This does the job. For different patterns though, or to also cover slight variations, you could go for a regex. For this example you'd need something like:

```
import re
[i for i in list1 if re.search(r'^uid=(\d+).*?', i).group(1) not in set2]
# ['uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it without loops

```
def filter_function(item):
    uid = int(item[4:].split('/')[0])
    if uid not in list2:
        return True
    return False


list1 = ['uid=123/2020/06/01/625e2ghvh.parquet','uid=876/2020/04/01/hgdshct7.parquet','uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']
list2 = [123, 876]

result_list = list(filter(filter_function, list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
_list2 = [f'uid={number}' for number in list2]
result = [item for item in list1 if not any([item.startswith(i) for i in _list2])]  # ['uid=0987/2019/03/01/323dc.parquet']
```